# Item em comboBox selecionado, exibir dados em jTable

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

Antes de fazer essa pergunta, procurei no fórum e em vários lugares mas não consegui resolver...

Tenho um comboBox que já carrega os nomes dos clientes, aí eu queria selecionar o cliente, e em um botão `ok` buscar esse cliente. Porém, na comparação de nomes, ele cai na mensagem de que não foi encontrado.

```
 private void btnBuscaClientesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTableClientes.getModel();
    String nomeCliente = comboClientes.getSelectedItem().toString();
    ConsultasDAO consulta = new ConsultasDAO();
    List<Cliente> clientes = null;
    try {
        clientes = consulta.getClientes();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro sql");
        //Logger.getLogger(TelaRelatorioGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    for (Cliente nomeClienteAtual : clientes) {
        if ((nomeCliente.toLowerCase()) == (nomeClienteAtual.getnome().toString().toLowerCase())) {
            model.addRow(new Object[]{nomeClienteAtual.getnome().toLowerCase(), nomeClienteAtual.gettelefone(), nomeClienteAtual.getrua(), nomeClienteAtual.getcomplemento()});
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cliente não encontrado");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, forneça um **[mcve]** para que seja possivel executar e testar o código, e propor uma solução.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparação de Strings em java não pode ser feita com o operador `==` porque é um tipo referência mas sim com `equals`. Logo este `if` não está correto:

```
if ((nomeCliente.toLowerCase()) == (nomeClienteAtual.getnome().toString().toLowerCase())) {
```

E corrigindo o `if` a mensagem também não está no sitio correto porque está no `else`. Dessa forma cada vez que passa por um cliente que não é o que se procura aparece uma mensagem.

Melhor seria assim:

```
int iguais = 0;
for (Cliente nomeClienteAtual : clientes) {
   if (nomeCliente.toLowerCase().equals(nomeClienteAtual.getnome().toString().toLowerCase()) {
      model.addRow(new Object[]{nomeClienteAtual.getnome().toLowerCase(), nomeClienteAtual.gettelefone(), nomeClienteAtual.getrua(), nomeClienteAtual.getcomplemento()});
      iguais++;
   } 
}

if (iguais == 0) {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cliente não encontrado");
}
```

Comment: poxa, muito obrigada mesmo! resolvido